# How to format user profile content to be printed on a printer?

Tags: theming

I'm building a recruiting website using the [eRecruiter profile distribution](http://drupal.org/project/recruiter) which uses [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) and was wondering if there is defined solution to creating a formatted page specifically for printing in D7 so the resumes can easily be printed in a nice format.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest is to create your separate CSS for print. If you have a custom theme you can add the css file in the theme's info file. This way you can hide regions you don't need on paper to be printed.